# Drupal install with composer (drupal-project)

Tags: 8, composer, installation-profiles

I have used option A to install Drupal 8 on server:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-manage-drupal-site-dependencies

https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project

But the site is listed in **public_html/drupal-project/web** while the root folder for the site is **public_html** ...

What to do?

See screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: That's right, anything managed by composer is placed outside of the main drupal folder as those should be managed with composer going forward. If you dont like the way it does this then composer probably isn't for you. Or you can use composer to just get a normal install with  he Option C from the drupal.org site you mentioned

Comment: From what I have read, I just need to change the web directory in Cpanel to point to public_html/drupal-project/web?

Comment: Yeah that's all that needs to be done

Comment: If your vendor folder is in the public_html folder, which is surely publicly accessible, you've kinda missed the point of using drupal-project

Comment: @Clive: it is pointing to the 'web' folder, NOT to public_html. I did not write it down correctly in my solution. I will correct it.